# Unable to re start up my react projects after the first time

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

Recently my projects would not want to start up for a second time after I run "npm start" I don't know why  it just start happening but these are the errors I get.

```
C:\Users\Vimalan\Desktop\React-Course\ReduxTutorial\tut>npm start

> tut@0.1.0 start C:\Users\Vimalan\Desktop\React-Course\ReduxTutorial\tut
> react-scripts start

'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! tut@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the tut@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Vimalan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-24T14_18_05_517Z-debug.log
```

and here's what it says in the log file

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.11
3 info using node@v14.15.5
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle tut@0.1.0~prestart: tut@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle tut@0.1.0~start: tut@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle tut@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle tut@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Vimalan\Desktop\React-Course\ReduxTutorial\tut\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Users\Vimalan\Desktop\sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3270200;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\Vimalan\Desktop\Neovim\bin;C:\Program Files\Vim\vim82;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Vimalan\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.54.0;C:\Users\Vimalan\AppData\Local\atom\atom.exe;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\bin\g++;C:\MinGW\bin\gcc;C:\Program Files\Heroku\bin;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin;C:\Users\Vimalan\Desktop\stripe;C:\Users\Vimalan\Desktop\stripe.exe;C:\Users\Vimalan\anaconda3;C:\Users\Vimalan\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\Vimalan\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\Vimalan\anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\Vimalan\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\Vimalan\Desktop\sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3270200;C:\Users\Vimalan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Vimalan\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\Vimalan\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Vimalan\AppData\Local\hyper\app-3.0.2\resources\bin;C:\Users\Vimalan\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\Heroku\bin;C:\Users\Vimalan\Desktop\stripe;C:\Users\Vimalan\Desktop\stripe.exe;
9 verbose lifecycle tut@0.1.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\Vimalan\Desktop\React-Course\ReduxTutorial\tut
10 silly lifecycle tut@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle tut@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle tut@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: tut@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid tut@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Vimalan\Desktop\React-Course\ReduxTutorial\tut
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v14.15.5
19 verbose npm  v6.14.11
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error tut@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the tut@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I've tried npm cache clean --force but that didn't work, a permanent solution would be great since most of the ones I've attempted to use were temporary.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting the `node_modules` folder and then run the `npm install` command in your project's root folder.